# CentOS virsh : how to inactive a container?

Tags: linux, centos, virsh

I am maintaining a legacy system(`redmine`). It is on `CentOS7 x86` and running on `virsh`.

I got a container(I do not know exact terms) with named `centos7-redmine`.

```
[root@ice]# virsh list --all
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
 1     centos7-redmine                running
```

I want to change max memory, so have to change this state to `inactive`. I already tried shutdown but it still `running`. Is there a way to change this to inactive?

```
[root@ice]# virsh shutdown centos7-redmine
Domain centos7-redmine is being shutdown

[root@ice]# virsh list --all
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
 1     centos7-redmine                running
```

Thanks. I think `virsh destory` sounds dangerous, since I have to maintain this image instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`virsh destory {name}` is the way to inactive. I have worried about `destory` command remove all data in the image but that did not happened.